# How to pull JSON data from an api and store it in mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, parsing

I am getting response from my api along with pagination and i want to parse some json data from it and store into my MongoDb database.

Please suggest how can i do it?

My MongoDb Schema :

```
var candidateInfo = new Schema({

    name:{type:String},
    lng: Number,
    lat: Number,
    address : {type:String},
    coords: { lng: Number, lat: Number},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    id : {type:String, unique:true}



});
```

Comment: What does the rest of your application look like?

Comment: This is either too vague, too broad, or both. Can you add some information on how you are connecting to mongodb, and be a little more specific with which part of the process you are having trouble with?